# Google Analytics for Single Page Application with # views

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics on Single Page Application. I'm trying to use Autotrack to track the virtual page views. But, it's not working.

Code:

```
<script>
        window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-1', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker', {
        shouldTrackUrlChange: function(newPath, oldPath) {
            newPath = newPath.split('?')[0];
            oldPath = oldPath.split('?')[0];
            return newPath != oldPath;
          }
        });
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
        <script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autotrack/0.6.4/autotrack.js"></script>
```

Comment: Two things. 1) You're using an old version, 1.1.0 is the current version. 2) What isn't working (be specific)? And have you tried using the [analytics.js debugger](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging)?

Comment: In the real-time dashboard in Google Analytics, it's only displaying "/" on active pages list. But in general it should display all the virtual pages that i visited in single page application when i change views. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wgp7ZhvzUxUGZEZ0tnMTBVWXc

Comment: You haven't given enough information for anyone to help you solve this. Either provide more information or I'm going to vote to close this question.

Comment: same problem here. I opened an issue on github https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/issues/146

Comment: my issue was closed because URL Fragments are not supported. Please note that if you change only #... parts, URL change will not be detected

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from related github issue:

"The urlChangeTracker plugin does not support tracking URL hash changes. This is mentioned in the [overview section](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/url-change-tracker.md#overview) of the plugin documentation.

Since almost all browsers in use today support the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), that's what you should be using when creating SPAs. Hash changes should only be used for in-page navigation to anchor links."